# How can I reference drawables of Project A from a Library Project B which Project A uses

Tags: android

I have an app project (A) and a library project (B). I need to use some drawables that exist in A in B.

A uses B as referenced library

I have tried doing com.A.R.drawables... bit it does not work it says "com... does not resolve to a variable"

Answer (score 0):

First, if "*I need to use some drawables that exist in A in B*" means **direct reference**, then it indicates bad design to me. You should not reference A's drawables from B directly but rather B should be told (via own methods, i.e. `setXXXDrawable()`) what are drawables to be used. It usually should be part of instantiation or initialization process of B in A's code.